# Object stores itself into DataBase

Tags: c++, database, qt

I am new in C++ and Qt and I am developing a simple app that stores and gets different types of employees in a Database. I implemented a hierarchy, Employee is the base class and then I have three different sub-classes : Monthly_Paid_Employee, Hourly_Paid_Employee and Salesman.

My coworker told me that a good solution is to use c++ polymorphism: the base class (Employee) has a virtual method and the sub-classes implement that method, so you can use pointers to the base class to manage all the instances of the sub-classes like in the next code:

```
Employee *e = new Salesman(name, salary, etc..);
e->insert();
```

Is that a good solution? I am asking that because in the University teachers taught me that the DAO pattern is better in order to have the DataBase stuff all together. The problem with a DAO class is that I would have to cast the Employee instance to the subclasses, loosing a lot of flexibility. With my coworker´s solution the code is everything but together, I will have a lot of code scattered in a lot of classes, but I have a lot more flexibility. Wich one is the best approach?

If there is a better solution I would be glad to know it.

Comment: `Single Responsibility Principle` claims that it is always good to divide data storing class and the same data processing class. But you don't have to agree with `SOLID`. But in this particular situation you can use polymorphism outside of DAO, and make something like `EmployerDbSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure If I have understood your problem well, but I would use polymorphism just as your co-worker recommended. This doesn't necessarily mean that the DAO responsibility has to be scattered across your program.

E.g.: 
In a primitive approach DAO class can have static methods for storing different kinds of employees

```
static void StoreEmplyee(...) {...}
static void StoreSalesmen(...) {...}
```

Then from the sub-classes you overwrite the insert function with calling the correct function from the DOA class.

```
class Salesman(...) {
//...
void insert() override {
DOA::insertSalesman(this);
}
};
```

This way the database handling as a responsibility remains in the DOA class, but you have the flexibility gained from polymorphism.

Another advice: Since the '11 standard C++ offers smart pointers - I would use those.

Comment: It is a good way to handle this problem. The only "bad" thing I can say is that to do some things I will have to call the DAO directily (for example a function to get all the salesman from the DataBase) and for other things I will have to call the DAO indirectily, calling first the function insert(), for example. It simplifies my code a lot though.

Comment: Hmm. I get your problem. I thought that employee->insert() is somehow necessary for your solution (and that's why I recommended this solution). If not then you should simply do: DOA:insertSalesman(e), where e is a pointer or reference to the object you want to save. And then DOA:getListOfEmployees() would be the function for getting all the Employees. The key point is to always think about whose responsibility is what you currently want to accomplish, and implement the logic there.

Comment: The thing if I do that is that is that I lose all the flexibility that managing all the subclasses with poiters to the base class gives me, because I would need to treat each instance separately (and the way my coworker says I call only once the Employee.insert() method and due to the polymorphism the correct method is called). It is a really (I think) common problem that I have never been taught to solve it properly.

Comment: I think you already know what you need to know :-) Coding is not black and white where a "THE BEST" solution exist. There are different approaches / solutions with different trade-offs. YOU, as the designer have to make the decision whether what's worth it. Maybe in your (small/big(?)) project polymorphism is the way, because it reduces code complexity even if such a solution goes against the SOLID principles. IMO the "ugly work" (creating the inserts for the different subclasses) has to be solved somewhere anyway. You might choose to do it int he employee class, others might choose it in DOA